# Problems with showing images over 2mb on webstite based on MVC with Razor

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, internet-explorer, razor

I'm pretty new to the MVC world. I'm programing with VS2010 using c#. Need a MVC based website to show some articles. The clients are all using IE8. Getting my data from database through EF.
Most of the articles have images which are stored in a folder and the path is stored in a MSSQL2008R2. Some of the images are bigger than 2mb (or more) and all of them are jpg.

So some of the images are showing on the website some are not, im getting the big red X that the image couldn't be displayed.

Do I have a buffer issue?

How can I fix this problem *without* rezising the images!?

------------------------------------view-----------------------------------

```
            @{if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(item.Foto))
              {
                <img src="../../Content/_image.jpg" alt="Kein Bild vorhanden" hight="100px" width="100px" />
              }                  
              else
              {
                <img alt="@realURL" src="@item.Foto" height="100px" width="100px" />                    
              }
            }
```

Comment: You should always add code snippets when you request for help

Comment: You could start by just resizing the images to 100x100px and not letting the browser do that. Then investigate _why_ IE displays a big red X. It does so for a reason. Is the image intact? How many images do you display? What do other browsers say? Anyway this is not MVC-related, just HTML and IE.

Comment: The images are intact, there are about 1000+ articles where 90% of them have images. Other browser didn't come to use b/c all clients are using IE. I'm sry that it is not related to MVC, i just have to fix this problem.

Comment: At 2mb each, those are pretty big images - do they need to be that big?

Comment: I wasn't really expecting an answer on my comment, but hoped it would set you back on the research track. There is no way anyone else can answer this, _you_ will have to investigate. Create a static HTML file that reproduces the behavior and update your question. You have to find out why the browser doesn't like your image. Is it valid image data, sent with correct headers, downloaded correctly, no memory problems because you chuck 1000's of images of 2 MB on a single page, and so on. Also **do** test it with a different browser. Chrome for example, installed in seconds, has great logging.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Images less than 2MB are displaying.  Images greater than 2MB are not displaying.  If you try to view an image larger than 2MB on some other website on the internet (using the same browser), does the image display?

You likely have a 2MB limit set on HTTP responses from your website. When the browser does a GET for the image `src` attribute, IIS sees that the response will be larger than 2MB and blocks it from being sent. Increase the response size limit and everything should be fine.

If you have Google Chrome, you can view the exact HTTP response you're getting when the browser tries to GET each image. For example, here's what one of the image GETs looks like when I visit google.com in debugging mode:

[image: Example]

I'm only hypothesizing as to the problem, since you don't provide many details.